# Настройка nginx proxy_pass с http на https

Tags: nginx, http, https

Дано: хост с двумя виртуалками, 1 внешний ip и 2 доменных имени. 
на виртуалках https. 
Трафик идет сначала на хост, и оттуда уже раскидывается по виртуалкам, в зависимости от того, на какой домен заходили. 
Прокси пасс корректно работает, если на виртуалках отсутствует ssl. 
Нужно, что бы работал и с ssl. 
Вопросы:

- Как это сделать без подключения сертификатов на хосте и отключения на
  виртуалках? Может ли это nginx? Если да, то как?
- Может быть есть возможность проксировать вообще весь трафик через
  него?

Хосты "на прямую", в обход прокси работают корректно. Пробовал модуль Stream, но победить его не смог. 
Конфиг и информация о nginx доступны по ссылке: https://pastebin.com/UP7F3hMM

Логи чистые. 
Браузер отдает корректный адрес и ошибку "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"
Вариант "отключить ssl на виртуалках и завести на хосте" не подходит.

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html вроде всё просто и понятно

Comment: Если вы не хотите терминировать ssl на хосте, то у вас только один вариант — stream. http-proxy не будет работать по определению

Comment: @AlexeyTen, пробовал его, но не разобрался как работать с данным модулем. Если других вариантов нет, то буду пытаться завести всё с ним. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен все-таки отказом от SSL на виртуалках.